# I can't install v8@3.15 on Mac M1 through homebrew

Tags: macos, homebrew, v8, macos-big-sur, apple-m1

the command I used : `arch -arm64 brew install v8@3.15`

here the error I'm getting :

```
Error: v8@3.15: no bottle available!
You can try to install from source with:
  brew install --build-from-source v8@3.15
Please note building from source is unsupported. You will encounter build
failures with some formulae. If you experience any issues please create pull
requests instead of asking for help on Homebrew's GitHub, Twitter or any other
official channels.
```

Answer (score 12):

This is because you haven't installed brew with with the `arch -arm64` option.

If you do it with these steps it should work:

```
$ arch -x86_64 /bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"
```

Append this to your .bashrc or .zshrc and source it:

```
 alias ibrew="arch -x86_64 brew"
 export PATH="/usr/local/homebrew/bin:$PATH"
```

Install libv8:

```
$ ibrew install v8@3.15
```

Install ruby (Probably a common case):

```
$ ibrew install rbenv
$ arch -x86_64 rbenv install <ruby_version>
$ arch -x86_64 rbenv global <ruby_version>
```

Append this to your .bashrc or .zshrc and source it:

```
eval "$(rbenv init -)"
```

Fix libv8 problem:

```
$ gem install libv8 -v '<your version>' -- --with-system-v8
$ gem install therubyracer -v '<your version>' -- --with-v8-dir=$(ibrew --prefix v8@3.15)
```

Comment: thank you Lucas I will try this asap this week probably .

Comment: While it's nice that this workaround exists for now, do note that it (1) will stop working if/when Apple stops supporting Rosetta for x86_64->arm64 translation; (2) incurs a significant performance overhead due to relying on Rosetta (which you might not care about, as is certainly better than things not working at all), and (3) exposes you to all the security issues found in 9+ year old software, so shouldn't be used for running untrusted code.

Comment: Still doesn't work in Mac OS Ventura. Macbook Pro M2

Comment: I am getting this error 
Error: v8@3.15 has been disabled because it depends on Python 2 to build!

Any idea how can i solve this?
Working on M2 pro chip currently.

Answer (score 4):

The message tells you that homebrew does not have an `arm64` build for v8@3.15.

If you check the Formular for [v8@3.15](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/master/Formula/v8@3.15.rb) you can see these lines:

```
  bottle do
    sha256 cellar: :any, big_sur:     "8d1b84feddb4827106ad10d573f41fc6f4c1ddf6cbc65d78d8e168d7ab541e07"
    sha256 cellar: :any, catalina:    "588e9a3b61c54705d918bc783e1aa2efa1fd31626ca20181c7fe3c38d0d50ca5"
    sha256 cellar: :any, mojave:      "38ef56c652ac4f91ec1ddac61b8719ffba4c949103a6636e15aa1cd768e2d14d"
    sha256 cellar: :any, high_sierra: "42c0c3b3f4dc7153023e14aef59c623f10c78ffe8f2d7a43ab984f2810a694dd"
    sha256 cellar: :any, sierra:      "4b845ce6a7fdc4110518dfbf48ab721d7f48b9e64f78e6d1cc199078ac9d874b"
    sha256 cellar: :any, el_capitan:  "9c191175be793dba50999f5ac1894f26b9eb39ca231f0618d5954833e5db8945"
    sha256 cellar: :any, yosemite:    "f3b4dddabc17df3d84c3e1bbd894fa33a60e221a150eb7ede77d64daaef1088b"
  end
```

There is no `arm64` build listed. It is might be (but I haven't checked that yet) that this version of v8 won't be compilable on arm64, or that there is no priority at the homebrew team to provide a bottle for it.

If you compare it with [v8](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/master/Formula/v8.rb) you can see that the latest version has `arm64` support.

```
  bottle do
    sha256 cellar: :any,                 arm64_big_sur: "40fe7744bd7dd356f3ded64b55e3e41583601a5fa747df259bacbd251e161a8c"
    sha256 cellar: :any,                 big_sur:       "68faad4ab0421a40086d0187e48dea562d1f429499073a93b653ac261f38e2b1"
    sha256 cellar: :any,                 catalina:      "3ce161a6680de885fd14d4c419ccc0a6061d75dbe4c2e94ac2f402004212f878"
    sha256 cellar: :any,                 mojave:        "6af3d70c93d53e095363fa0ccf7a4e2e725cfef3ca0b7584ebe32a653460cb72"
    sha256 cellar: :any_skip_relocation, x86_64_linux:  "af6919d3fb249b607ee98e1dba60ecb70b53c2ce07db1cf33eb8f917950f51ad"
  end
```

Comment: thanks , this is annoying as an M1 macbook user I need v8@3.15 to install therubyracer so frustrating

Answer (score 0):

V8 3.15 is from December 2012 and as such about 8 years too old to work on Apple M1 hardware. Try using V8 9.2, the current stable version. (I think M1 was officially supported in 8.7 and later.)

M1 and V8 aside, nobody should be using an 8-year-old JavaScript engine, for anything.

Comment: I know but  I need v8@3.15 to install therubyracer gem this is  so frustrating

Comment: this making me regret jumping too soon to the M1 wave

Comment: Sounds like therubyracer seriously needs an update.

Comment: they need to make compatible with M1 devices

Comment: @سعيد Have you found a solution to this problem? I have the same problem and know how annoying this is. Fk M1

Comment: @Lukas-.- nope I just gave up  since it wasn't worth the effort , I originally wanted to use ruby gems in some study projects . yeah the fk m1 chip I'm really considering going back to intel tbh .

Comment: For new projects, https://github.com/rubyjs/mini_racer may be an alternative: it appears to be better maintained than therubyracer. (I'm not involved with it and can't vouch for it, just found it by searching.)

Comment: @سعيد I found a solution, if you still new help, contact me

Comment: @Lukas-.- here is my twitter  SaiduSenpay if you wanna stay in touch also my github https://github.com/Saidfatah

Answer (score 0):

Homebrew have already disabled v8@3.15 -> https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/v8@3.15

I have an easy solution, you can use this link to download the official v8 content https://github.com/v8/v8/archive/3.15.11.18.tar.gz

This content should be copied to usr/local/opt/

nit: you can rename the folder to v8@3.15.

Hope this works, Happy Coding!!